# how to increment the hour of Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice, every second

Tags: react-native

im trying to figure out how to increment Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice by 1 for each second. in order for my question to make more sense, i need to show you my code:

heres the time in state:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
```

the method newOrder(timeAsProp) converts the time from '12:00:00', into '12'.

```
newOrder(timeAsProp) {
    const hour = timeAsProp.slice(0, 2);
```

the method newOrder(timeAsProp) then assigns a new image order for each hour like this:
(basically, i would like to have the 'hour' increment by 1, each second, so that i can see a new image order every second, instead of every hour (for testing purposes))

```
 newOrder(timeAsProp) {
    const hour = timeAsProp.slice(0, 2);
    let returnValue = [];
    const yud = <Image key="yud" source={require('./img/yud.png')} style={Style.image} />;
    const hey1 = <Image key="hey1" source={require('./img/hey1.png')} style={Style.image} />;
    const vav = <Image key="vav" source={require('./img/vav.png')} style={Style.image} />;
    const hey2 = <Image key="hey2" source={require('./img/hey2.png')} style={Style.image} />;

    if (hour === '00' || hour === '12') {
       returnValue = [     
        yud, hey1, vav, hey2
        ];  
    }
    if (hour === '01' || hour === '13') {
        returnValue = [     
        yud, hey1, hey2, vav
        ];
    }
```

for testing purposes, i would like to increment 
 "hour", each second by 1, so that i can see the images change every second, instead of every hour, to see everything works properly.

im new to coding, and tried seeing if any other questions adressed this issue first, but could not find, so please forgive me if this has already been answered.
 i already tried this: (but its not helping)

```
currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + 1
```

im sure it must be a simple solution but i cant figure it out. im guessing if i can save: "const hour" in state, and then have that update every second that might work... but again as i said, im new to all this and can use all the help i can get.   thnks!
sb

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) great library for dealing with time and date.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt help me. i checked out the link, and it doesnt have what im looking for.
 basically, i have the current time parsed down to TWO digits.
 i want to increment those digits each second. thats all.